# Trying to capure text few lines below with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture the text **This is ABC**

with my regex

`(?<=Verified Data\n)(.*?)(?=</div>)`

my problem is it is located 6 lines below the verified data. What is the regex to capture that?

---

```
Verified Data 
 </span>





<div class="a-section">
 This is ABC
</div>

</div>
```

but i'm lost.

here's the quick look

http://regex101.com/r/mV6jU6/1

Answer (score 1):

```
Verified Data[\s\S]*?<div[^>]+>\s*(.*?)\s*(?=<\/div>)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/mV6jU6/2

Comment: it doesnt work exactly for my project but you laid out the foundation for me to learn more

Answer (score 0):

I try this will capture strictly in regex.

```
Verified Data\s*(?:(?!<\/?div[ >]).)*\s*<div[^>]+>\s*((?:(?!<\/div[ >]).)*)\s*<\/div>
```

get grap with group1.

**SEE DEMO:**  http://regex101.com/r/mV6jU6/3